# Why does Visual Studio start both asp.net and asmx webservice on F5?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have set my asp.net web application as the startup project. It is configured to "Use Local IIS Web server + Use IIS Express" with localhost:8083

But when I start, it also starts my other project in the same solution, on localhost:8082 which is an asmx webservice. Why does it do that and where is it configured to do so?

Comment: Is your other project a web service project? The Web tab in the project properties has details about which web server to use when running/debugging that project

Comment: well yes, but I didnt start the other project so why does it get started as well.